# Scanning whole words with Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to implement Pattern with a regex = \w (or all words).

When I run the program output should be:

```
a [1]
is [1]
test[1,2]
```

but instead it is:

```
a [1]
e [2]
h [1]
i [1, 1]
s [1, 1, 2]
t [1, 2, 2]
```

The code responsable for Scanning and Pattern Matching is below:

```
public class DocumentIndex {

  private TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = 
  new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();       // Stores words and their locations
  private String regex = "\\w";                //any word

  /**
   * A constructor that scans a document for words and their locations
   */
  public DocumentIndex(Scanner doc){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);       //Pattern class: matches words
    Integer location = 0;                   // the current line number
        // while the document has lines
        // set the Matcher to the current line
        while(doc.hasNextLine()){
            location++;
            Matcher m = p.matcher(doc.nextLine());
            // while there are value in the current line
            // check to see if they are words
            // and if so save them to the map
            while(m.find()){
                if(map.containsKey(m.group())){
                    map.get(m.group()).add(location);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    list.add(location);
                    map.put(m.group(), list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

What is the best way to read the whole word as a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\\w+`, not `\\w`.  The latter will only match one character (the former, one or more chars).

Answer (score 0):

`([^ ]+)+`

Or you can use the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class.